# Python: For-loop won't finish

Tags: python, for-loop

Before I start let me just say that I'm really new to programming so please don't kill me.

As an exercise I wrote a script that is supposed to take a list of hex numbers from a txt, convert them to decimal and write them to another file. This is what I came up with:

```
hexdata = open(raw_input("Sourcefile:")).read().split(',')
dec_data = []

print hexdata
x = -1
for i in hexdata:
    next_one = hexdata.pop(x+1)
    decimal = int(next_one, 16)
    print "Converting: ", next_one, "Converted:", decimal
    dec_data.append(decimal)

print dec_data

target = open(raw_input("Targetfile: "), 'w')
for n in dec_data:
    output = str(n)
    target.write(output)
    target.write(",")
```

When I run the script it finishes whithout errors however it only converts and writes the first 30 numbers from my sourcefile and ignores all the other ones, even though they are loaded into the 'hexdata' list. I've tried several variations but it never works with all the numbers (48). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `hexdata.pop(x+1)` seems strange...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first loop is trying to iterate over hexdata, while at the same time pulling values out of the list using hexdata.pop().  Just change it to something like:

```
for next_one in hexdata:
    decimal = int(next_one, 16)
    print "Converting: ", next_one, "Converted:", decimal
    dec_data.append(decimal)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that would cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The principle when iterating over lists is to not modify the list you're iterating over.  If you have to, you can make a copy of the list to iterate over.

```
for i in hexdata[:]: # this creates a shallow copy, or a slice of the entire list
    next_one = hexdata.pop(x+1)
    decimal = int(next_one, 16)
    print "Converting: ", next_one, "Converted:", decimal
    dec_data.append(decimal)
```

You can also create a deep copy using [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), which will allow you to avoid the issues posed in shallow copies, such as `hexdata[:]`.

Comment: I would like to note that `hexdata[:]` is **not** a deep copy (not that you need one here, but it's misleading to say it is one). That is a shallow copy. For a deep copy, you need [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). Also, even for a shallow copy, that's unclear syntax `list(hexdata)` or `copy.copy(hexdata)` would be better for a shallow copy.

Comment: You're right @Lattyware, I'll update my answer to reflect that.